# Remotely search WordPress sites using xml-rpc

Tags: custom-post-types, search, xml-rpc

This is the scenario: 
There are say 3 sites - A, B and C.
Sites A and B have several custom posts. Now, from site C, I'd like to make a search for the posts in sites A and B.

After reading up through online resources, I realized that xml-rpc can be used to achieve this. I read about adding custom functions, but I didn't understand where exactly the add_filter method is to be put (along with the custom method definition).

Can someone guide me along?